# Why do I need to refresh my wallet?

Tags: full-node, monero-wallet-cli, refresh

If I run a full node on the same computer as simplewallet why do I need to "refresh" my wallet to see new incoming and outgoing transactions?

Will the new official GUI now in development eliminate the need to do this by better integrating the wallet with the full node?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"Refreshing" means telling the wallet to check the blockchain to see if any transactions were sent or received in any blocks added to the chain since it last looked. This makes it clearer why this has to be done,

If you want the wallet to refresh automatically, try `set auto-refresh 1` in thw wallet. This needs a recent enough wallet, and it might not be in the binaries yet.

The GUI will almost certainly have the ability to auto refresh too. And if not, it will be added pretty fast.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this option is available in any binary that supports the hard fork, so if you're synced then it should work.